Google Cloud SQL-dumps randomly fail with a permission error
In an automated database backup, the databases are exported into a Google Bucket by the command:
gcloud sql export sql "$INSTANCE" "gs://db-backup-temp-storage/${INSTANCE_PREFIX}_${DB}_dump.gz" --database="${DB}"

A few days ago, this command has started to fail most of the time (~ 80 %). When it is executed multiple times after failure, it works after a few tries.
The error message is:
$ gcloud --verbosity=debug sql export sql "$INSTANCE" "gs://db-backup-temp-storage/${INSTANCE_PREFIX}_${DB}_dump.gz" --database="${DB}"
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.sql.export.sql] with arguments: [--database: "['staging_tool_tool']", --verbosity: "debug", INSTANCE: "prd-pg", URI: "gs://db-backup-temp-storage/pg_staging_tool_tool_dump.gz"]
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): sqladmin.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://sqladmin.googleapis.com:443 "POST /sql/v1beta4/projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/instances/prd-pg/export?alt=json HTTP/1.1" 403 None
DEBUG: (gcloud.sql.export.sql) HTTPError 403: The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket. This command is authenticated as prod-rundeck-kubectl@<PROJECT_NAME>.iam.gserviceaccount.com which is the active account specified by the [core/account] property.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 998, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 842, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/sql/export/sql.py", line 75, in Run
    return export_util.RunSqlExportCommand(args, client)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/sql/export_util.py", line 146, in RunSqlExportCommand
    return RunExportCommand(args, client, sql_export_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/sql/export_util.py", line 91, in RunExportCommand
    result_operation = sql_client.instances.Export(export_request)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/generated_clients/apis/sqladmin/v1beta4/sqladmin_v1beta4_client.py", line 832, in Export
    return self._RunMethod(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 747, in _RunMethod
    return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 753, in ProcessHttpResponse
    self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 612, in __ProcessHttpResponse
    raise exceptions.HttpError.FromResponse(
apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpForbiddenError: HttpError accessing <https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/instances/prd-pg/export?alt=json>: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'date': 'Wed, 09 Oct 2024 14:16:56 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': 403}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "notAuthorized"
      }
    ]
  }
}
>
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.export.sql) HTTPError 403: The service account does not have the required permissions for the bucket. This command is authenticated as prod-rundeck-kubectl@<PROJECT_NAME>.iam.gserviceaccount.com which is the active account specified by the [core/account] property.

When analyzing the permissions on the cloud console (IAM & Admin → Service Accounts → prod-rundeck-kubectl@<PROJECT_NAME>.iam.gserviceaccount.com → Permissions → View Access → Analyze) the service account has the permissions "Storage Object Admin" and "Cloud SQL Editor", as the documentation mentions.
What is strange is that the export works when retrying the command without changing anything, which makes it seem like it is not actually a permission problem.
Does anyone know what the cause could be or how to debug it?
